# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement for Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pycharm

I am trying to modify data in a table in a database on my personal computer for practice, but I keep receiving this error in the run console (using PyCharm):

```
Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

This is my code:

```py
import mysql.connector
from employee import Employee


def add_employee(employee):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="taker0923",
        database="employee"
    )

    cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO employee(id, name, email, phoneNumber, salary) " \
                "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        values = (employee.employee_ID, employee.full_name, employee.email, employee.phone_number, employee.salary)

        cursor.execute(query, values)
        mydb.commit()
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()


def delete(employee_id):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="taker0923",
        database="employee"
    )

    cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    try:
        query = "DELETE FROM employee " \
                "WHERE id = %s"

        empid = tuple(employee_id)
        cursor.execute(query, empid)
        mydb.commit()
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()


def update(empid, column, new_value):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="taker0923",
        database="employee"
    )

    cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    try:
        query = "UPDATE employee " \
                "SET %s = %s " \
                "WHERE id = %s"

        if column == 'name':
            values = (column, new_value, empid)
            cursor.execute(query, values)
        elif column == 'email':
            values = (column, new_value, empid)
            cursor.execute(query, values)
        elif column == 'phoneNumber':
            values = (column, new_value, empid)
            cursor.execute(query, values)
        elif column == 'salary':
            values = (column, new_value, empid)
            cursor.execute(query, values)
        elif column == 'id':
            raise ValueError("Cannot update this column")
        else:
            raise ValueError("ERROR: Could not find matching column")

        mydb.commit()
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()


def find(employee_id):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="taker0923",
        database="employee"
    )

    cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    try:
        query = "SELECT %s FROM employee " \
                "WHERE id = %s"

        cursor.execute(query, tuple(employee_id))

        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print(record)

        mydb.commit()
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()


def display_all():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="taker0923",
        database="employee"
    )

    cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    try:
        query = 'SELECT * FROM employee'
        cursor.execute(query)

        records = cursor.fetchall()
        print(f'Total number of rows: {cursor.rowcount}')

        for row in records:
            print(f'ID = {row[0]}')
            print(f'Name = {row[1]}')
            print(f'Email: = {row[2]}')
            print(f'Phone Number: = {row[3]}')
            print(f'Salary: = {row[4]}')

    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()


def main():
    print("1- Add new employee")
    print("2- Delete student by employee ID")
    print("3- Edit employee information")
    print("4- Search employee by ID")
    print("5- Display all employees")

    option = int(input("Enter option: "))

    if option == 1:
        emp_id = input("Enter employee ID: ")
        name = input("Enter employee's name: ")
        email = input("Enter employee's email: ")
        phone_number = input("Enter employee's phone number: ")
        salary = int(input("Enter employee's salary (rounded to nearest whole number): "))

        obj = Employee(emp_id, name, email, phone_number, salary)
        add_employee(obj)

        print(f'You have successfully added {emp_id} - {name} into the system!')

    elif option == 2:
        emp_id = input("Enter employee ID: ")
        delete(emp_id)

        print(f'You have successfully deleted ID  #{emp_id} from the system!')

    elif option == 3:
        print("\n1- Name")
        print("2- Email")
        print("3- Phone Number")
        print("4- Salary")

        choice = int(input("Which column do you want to edit? "))
        empid = input("Enter the employee's ID number: ")
        new_value = input("Enter new value: ")

        if choice == 1:
            update(empid, 'name', new_value)
            print("Successfully updated record")
        elif choice == 2:
            update(empid, 'email', new_value)
            print("Successfully updated record")
        elif choice == 3:
            update(empid, 'phoneNumber', new_value)
            print("Successfully updated record")
        elif choice == 4:
            new_value = int(new_value)
            update(empid, 'salary', new_value)
            print("Successfully updated record")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid selection")

    elif option == 4:
        empid = input("Enter the employee's ID number: ")
        find(empid)

    elif option == 5:
        display_all()

    else:
        raise ValueError("ERROR: Invalid selection")


main()
```

Whenever I try to delete, update, or search for a specific row in my table, I receive that error. The columns in my table are: id, name, email, phoneNumber, salary, typed exactly the same way. However, I am able to successfully insert new data and query all data in the table. Am I doing anything wrong, and if so what? How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

#### Delete

Your error here appears to be a misunderstanding of what `tuple(employee_id)` does. `tuple(1)` raises the exception `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, but you don't appear to be getting that error, so I can only conclude that your IDs are strings.

So, what does happen if you call `tuple` on a string value? This:

```
>>> tuple("123")
('1', '2', '3')
```

You get a tuple with each element containing a single character from the string.

If your string happens to have one character in it, perhaps your statement will execute as expected. But if it is any longer than that, you will attempt to run a `DELETE` statement with one parameter and two or more values. Hence your error.

The fix here is to replace `tuple(employee_id)` with `(employee_id,)` (note that the comma here is intentional) which is how you write a tuple with one element in Python. Or you can use a list instead, `[employee_id]`, as that avoids the trailing comma.

#### Update

The query you are attempting to use to update an employee is as follows:

```py
        query = "UPDATE employee " \
                "SET %s = %s " \
                "WHERE id = %s"
```

The problem is that you can't use bind parameters for column names. Bind parameters can only be used to put values into SQL, and a column name is not a value.

Instead, you will have to concatenate the column value directly into the SQL:

```py
        query = "UPDATE employee " \
                f"SET {column} = %s " \
                "WHERE id = %s"
```

You are currently only executing the `UPDATE` statement if the column name is
one of `name`, `email`, `phoneNumber` or `salary`, so there isn't a risk of SQL injection here. However, as the code in the first for `if` ... `elif` ... `elif` ... branches is the same, you could simplify your code as follows:

```py
        if column in ('name', 'email', 'phoneNumber', 'salary'):
            values = (new_value, empid)
            cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Note that I've taken out `column` from `values`, as by the time we reach this point it's already in the SQL string.

#### Find

Here, we see the same problems as in the previous two cases:

```py
        query = "SELECT %s FROM employee " \
                "WHERE id = %s"

        cursor.execute(query, tuple(employee_id))
```

Here, you are using `%s` where we probably want a column name, and you are also using `tuple(employee_id)` again.

The latter problem we can fix using `(employee_id,)` or `[employee_id]` as we did before. However it is less clear how to fix the former problem. There's no indication from your code what column you want to select. Maybe you want to select all columns, as you do with `query_all`?  In this case you'll need `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT %s`.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much for the detailed answer! I'm in the process of learning Python and MySQL with it, I greatly appreciate this answer

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n